# Suggesting a synonym has some issues

Tags: discussion, bug, tag-synonyms

I've found some people talking around these things, but not directly on point. There's a few issues I've noticed about the synonym system:

1. Tag A is like Tag B, but you can't suggest that unless you've got a score of 5 in Tag B. There's two problems with this. For active tags this is fine but what if you're proposing one for a tag that is a small subset of a tag you have a score in? And how do you earn a score in a tag without any real traffic?
2. Can we add the auto-populate into the synonym suggestion box? It's very handy in making posts but missing here. You have to type the tag exactly as it appears to make it work which is unintuitive for a site that goes to great lengths to help you tag posts.
3. I'm not sure if this is a bug (feel free to remove [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) if it's not) but trying to suggest a synonym had produced this strange error:

> A synonym from **Tag A** to **Tag B** exists, chains are not allowed

I got it trying to suggest [paypalmerchantsdk](/questions/tagged/paypalmerchantsdk) as a synonym to [paypal-api](/questions/tagged/paypal-api) (which, as far as I can tell, has no synonyms). Just for kicks I tried it with [chained-payments](/questions/tagged/chained-payments) and got the same thing.

EDIT

I found that in the category PayPal there was an active pending vote to make [paypal-api](/questions/tagged/paypal-api) a synonym of [paypal](/questions/tagged/paypal). I wonder if that's the source of the problem. Could just be a poor error message. If so, it should tell you there's a vote to turn one of your synonyms into a synonym of another category.

Comment: Apparently [tag:paypal-api] is a synonym of [tag:paypal].

Comment: Yeah, after posting this I went to the main PayPal category where I found it had been suggested and had 3 upvotes so I added mine to make it happen. I hadn't wanted to suggest it myself because there are other non-API questions but I guess that's moot now. It could explain what caused my error (pending vote precludes you from suggesting) but why doesn't the error message say that then?

Comment: Ooh, that makes sense. I agree, then that is a bug, as it should tell you there is an *active* proposed tag synonym vs. there's already one existing.